# Как задать ширину в % от родительского View в storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard

Есть ViewController, внутри которого необходимо расположить в ряд три Picker'a одинаковой ширины. Как это реализовать?

Comment: я так понимаю автор вопроса хотел, чтобы под любой экран пикеры равномерно распределялись по всей ширине родителя занимая все место

Answer (score 1):

Левый пикер:

- отступ левого края от левого края родителя = 0 (leading edge)
- ширина левого равна ширине среднего (equal width)

Средний пикер:

- leading среднего пикера = trailing левого пикера
- ширина среднего равна ширине правого (equal width)

Правый пикер:

- отступ от правого края родителя = 0 (trailing edge)
- leading правого пикера = trailing среднего пикера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
NSInteger numberOfPickers = 3; 

CGFloat pickerWidth = self.view.frame.size.width/numberOfPickers;

for(int i =0; i< numberOfPickers; i++) {
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(i*pickerWidth, 0, pickerWidth, 100);
    UIPickerView *picker = [UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    [self.view addSubview:picker];
}
```

Comment: А можно сделать это как-то не программно? Я пишу на swift

Comment: А в чем тогда проблема? В IB добавляете три UIPickerView и задаете им нужную ширину и высоту.

Answer (score 0):

- Если хотите сделать только в IB, то используйте [UIStackView](https://www.raywenderlich.com/114552/uistackview-tutorial-introducing-stack-views).
- Если хотите сделать в коде, то используйте [UILayoutGuide](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/goodbye-spacer-views-hello-layout-guides/).